# maganeto ajax product detail pop up

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

i had installed theme it was fine when i click product detail quick view after installing lots of plugin / modules i noticed that product detail pages started displaying with header and footer in pop up to ,

i could not figure out how to resolve it as there are lots of custom mudules used and also i made some changes in few modules , uninstalling them will be a great problem

see http://bellb2b.com/

in quick view product shows header footer any way to resolve this via controller or any easy way?.. please guide

while inspecting element i found page called to be :
frontend\buyshop\default\template\page/1column.phtml

but earlier in fresh installation page called for ajax was:
frontend\base\default\template\page/empty.phtml

how can i override file to be used in case of ajax pop up page call

Comment: I cant seem to find the quick view your referring. I think the issue there is that when you installed more modules that cause a different phtml file was called.

Comment: please click quick view on that page